# jQuery mouseenter/leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in html:

```
<div class="sub-status">
    <p class="subscribed"><i class="icon-check"></i> Subscribed</p>
</div>
```

On hover, I want that to be changed to:

```
<div class="sub-status">
    <p class="unsubscribe"><i>X</i> Unsubscribe</p>
</div>
```

And, I have this code in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sub-status').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).html("<p class='unsubscribe'><i>X</i> Unsubscribe</p>");
    });
    $('.sub-status').mouseleave(function() {
        $('this').html("<p class='subscribed'><i class='icon-check'></i> Subscribed</p>");
    });
});
```

The first function is working great. When I mouseover that div, it is changed to what I want, but the mouseleave is not working. I want that when I put my mouse out of that div, its data will return to like it was before. I can't get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try this. Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XrYj4/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sub-status').on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).find("p").prop("class", "unsubscribed").html("<i>X</i> Unsubscribe");
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).find("p").prop("class", "subscribed").html("<i class='icon-check'></i> Subscribed");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I just changed the UNSUBSCRIBED class to UNSUBSCRIBE and excellent. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
$('this')...
```

to

```
$(this)...
```

And you can use `hover()` instead of using two separate functions:

```
$('.sub-status').hover(function() {
    $(this).html("<p class='unsubscribe'><i>X</i> Unsubscribe</p>");
},function() {
    $(this).html("<p class='subscribed'><i class='icon-check'></i> Subscribed</p>");
});
```

### Updated

Your fiddle isn't working since you are updating the entire content of the hovered element - update just the text in `<p>` should work.

```
$('.sub-status').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('p')
              .removeClass()
              .addClass('unsubscribed')
              .html("<i>X</i> Unsubscribe");
  },function() {
     $(this).children('p')
               .removeClass()
               .addClass('subscribed')
               .html("<i class='icon-check'></i> Subscribed");
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/XrYj4/5/)

Comment: I discourage the use of hover() because that triggers an insane amount of executions, which is not necessary in this case.

Comment: `an insane amount of executions..` ?? can u explain ??

Comment: @bipen put a console.log in your hover function and see what happens in the console

Comment: @php_nub_qq i don't see any difference with mouseenter/mouseleave. Could you elaborate on issue hover could have?

Comment: @php_nub_qq .. have you tried that with seperate function ..like you have in your answer?? and yes `hover() is shorthand for $(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);` there is no difference

Comment: @php_nub_qq i really think you are talking about onmouseover event instead

Comment: It's not working again. I get the same effect. The text is changed on mouseenter, but not after I leave.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a hover function:

```
$(".sub-status").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).html("<p class='unsubscribe'><i>X</i> Unsubscribe</p>");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).html("<p class='subscribed'><i class='icon-check'></i> Subscribed</p>");
  }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: It's not working again. I get the same effect. The text is changed on mouseenter, but not after I leave.

Answer (score 1):

Change `'this'` to simply `this`. Also consider chaining, shown below, this helps users with weaker devices load stuff faster.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sub-status').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).html("<p class='unsubscribe'><i>X</i> Unsubscribe</p>");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).html("<p class='subscribed'><i class='icon-check'></i> Subscribed</p>");
    });
});
```

Comment: @smerny that is really weird